# PHP Warning : A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: errors

I get this Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/boombox/includes/functions.php on line 2466

I try to change it from => $manual_amount + $user_votes; to  $manual_amount += $user_votes; (it throws same warning) and $manual_amount . $user_votes;  (it concatenates the numbers, does not add them)

```
 /**
 * Return post point count
 *
 * @param $post_id
 *
 * @return int
 */
function boombox_get_post_point_count($post_id)
{
    $points_count = 0;
    /*if ( boombox_module_management_service()->is_module_active( 'prs' ) ) {
        $points_count = Boombox_Point_Count_Helper::get_post_points( $post_id );
    }*/
    $manual_amount = get_post_meta($post_id, "manual_vote_amount", true);
    $user_votes = get_post_meta($post_id, "add_vote_amount", true);
    $points_count = $manual_amount + $user_votes;
    return $points_count;
}
```

I'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post meta values are stored as *strings* in the database, so you get only strings back. If you want to use these value in mathematical operations, you have to [cast the value to a numeric type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting), meaning you write the desired type in parentheses in front of the variable or the function call.

Generic example:

```
$number = (int) get_post_meta($post_id, "key_identifier", true);
```

And then you can use the variable with a `+` sign.